# How to brute force html parse a json string OR how to fix "\xfc" in <type 'str'> in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `<type 'str'>` variable containing some html. My problem is that the special characters are encoded like such `"\xfc"` instead of `"ü"` when printed to the console.

I already tried to do

```
html = html.encode('utf-8').decode('string_escape')
```

but no success. Can anyone guide me into the right direction?

Thanks!

**Update:**

The problem is not yet solved. Here is some more information about the problem...

I am receiving a json string from an external source that contains html besides some other stuff. I want to access the html with xpath in a "brute force approach" since the json structure changes frequently.

So I figured to use beautiful soup.

For that I pass the json string to json.loads() which turns it into an object. Then I typecast the json object to a plain string and pass that to beautiful soup.

The approach works quite good, except for special characters such as ßäüöÄÜÖ.

What would be the best approach to fix that?

This is some pseudo code

```
data = json.loads(jsonstring)
html = str(data) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
html = soup.prettify()
html = "<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head>" + html + "</body></html>"

print type(html)
print html
```

This is a typical result returned by beautiful soup (see the **Haus f\xfcr Belgien**)

```
 <div class="sr_color">
          <div style="float:left">
           <a class="sr_color" href="">
            Haus f\xfcr Belgien
           </a>
           :
           <span>
            <span class="sr_num_color">
             5,0
            </span>
            <span style="display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;float:none;vertical-align:-1px" class="star">
             <span style="width:65px">
              &nbsp;
             </span>
            </span>
           </span>
          </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Your string does not actually contain the character sequence `\xfc` - that's just python's way of telling you it contains an `0xfc` byte

Answer (score 2):

`\xfc` is the representation of `ü` in `latin1`.

First, decode your html into unicode, and then print it using the appropriate encoding for your console:

```
u = html.decode('latin1')  # u is an unicode string
print u.encode('utf-8')    # u.encode('utf-8') is a bytestring, encoded in utf-8
```

---

Be mindful that:

- `decode` goes from bytestrings to unicode
- `encode` goes from unicode to bytestrings

Bytestrings (`str` in Python 2, `bytes` in Python 3) are what you use for input (e.g. your HTML) and output (e.g. your console). Unicode (`unicode` in Python 2, `str` in Python 3) is what you should use in your program.

Comment: I tried your suggestion like html = html.decode('latin1').encode('utf-8'); print html; print type(html) but the type of the html variable is still <'str'>. Shouldn't it be unicode? I'm totally confused with this encoding in python...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your console supports unicode? Python could be dealing with the character just fine, but when it gets printed, your terminal might not be interpreting it correctly. Try writing the string to a file and opening it with some editor that supports unicode (or even an html file and opening it in your browser).

Most terminal emulators support multiple encodings which can be set in their options (depending on the terminal emulator in question).

Comment: jepp. at least this works...  test= u' K\xfcchen- und Haushaltsartikel';print type(test);print test -> output Küchen- und Haushaltsartikel